# Are the chargers the same on the iPad and the iPad 2?

Tags: charging, ipad, compatibility

Is the charger of iPad and iPad 2 same? I want to buy i extra charger for my iPad but in future I can buy iPad 2 also. So I want to buy a charge which should be compatible with iPad and ipad 2 both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The charger is 10W like the old iPad. It's called **iPad 10W USB Power Adapter** and has product number **MC359LL**. Specs and QnA are available at the Apple US [online store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC359LL/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY).

Answer (score 3):

I have an iPad and my wife has an iPad 2. It's too dark in my house to look at the power adapters right now but they are either identical, or close enough to not matter. They are both 10W. We interchange them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably also useful to know that you can also charge an iPad using any iPhone or iPod Touch charger. It will charge a lot slower when not using the iPad specific charge, but it will still charge it.

The non-iPad chargers don't however provide enough power to charge the iPad while it is using used, they will provide enough to stop it discharging though.